# Maven Jar Encoding Problem

Tags: plugins, encoding, utf-8, jar, maven

How do I specify (or "force") the maven jar plugin to use my specific encoding (UTF-8) ?

My build plugin :

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.1</version>
<executions>
 <execution>
  <phase>package</phase>
  <id>configurations-test</id>
  <goals>
   <goal>jar</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
   <classesDirectory>target/test</classesDirectory>
   <forceCreation>true</forceCreation>
   <finalName>${artifactId}-test</finalName>
   </excludes>
  </configuration>
 </execution>
</executions></plugin>
```

I set the encoding in the parent pom and every copies is executed with the right encoding

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```

I controled the files just before the Jar is created, these are well formated.

Note, I did many tried addind specific encoding to the configuration but it still won't work, in my packaged Jars I found unwell formatted characters (like Ã©, which should be é)

The unzipped files (html, xml, properties etc.) contains such characters like Ã© instead of é.

Comment: What do you mean, you found characters in your jar? In what sort of file on your jar? A class? XML? Property? file names of the files of the jar?

Comment: When I unzip the results jars, the files aren't well formated.

Comment: The unzipped files (html, xml, properties etc.) contains such characters like Ã© instead of é

Answer (score 0):

jar doesn't mess with your files. It just copies the bytes. On the other hand, the resource plugin might.

You need to set `${project.build.sourceEncoding}`.

See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html.

Comment: ${project.build.sourceEncoding} is set. copy-resources works well, files are well-formatted copied. in my example, into target/test the files are correct but in the results jar the zipped files are wrong formatted

Comment: Got it, seems that some files are still encoded as ISO-8859-1 in the repository. I've to find them, change the encoding to UTF-8 and all will be fine

Comment: I apologize, I misread the the property as being different than the one you set, not the same.

Answer (score 0):

specify UTF encoding property:

> ```
> <properties>
>     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF</project.build.sourceEncoding>
> </properties>
> ```

be warned, i've experienced the following error when I use UTF encoding deploying to wls 10.3.6, not sure others.

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: unsupported archive type:
>   zip:/oracle/fmwhome/user_projects/domains/dev_soa_osb/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/myicarus-201609261658/131q4y/war/WEB-INF/lib/dummybean-spring-1.0.0.jar!/.

not sure how to configure wls to read utf zips

so now i'm using ASCII as the encoding, and wls doesn't complain